# Bias and variance of estimator

Tags: statistics, estimation, parameter-estimation

I have the following estimator,  $E = 1/\bar{X}$ of $E = 1/\lambda$ where X is exponentially distributed with parameter $\lambda$. I'm trying to find the bias and variance of this estimator. For the bias I have calculated it as $E(1/\lambda - 1/\bar{X})$ so it should be asymptotically unbiased. For the variance of the estimator I get $E((1/\bar{X})^2 - (E(1/\bar{X}))^2)$ but I'm not confident witht his result. Could someone verify or provide a derivation for the correct results?

Comment: To get our best assistance with your calculus, it would be best to show us the (mysterious) result of which you are not confident.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although your notation is nonstandard, I believe you are checking properties of the estimator
$\hat \lambda = 1/\bar X$ of $\lambda$ for a random sample
of size $n$ from $Exp(rate = \lambda).$ An unbiased version
of the estimate is $\tilde \lambda = (n-1)/\sum X_i$.

For comparison with your analytical results, here are some
simulated results (using R) for the case $n=10$ and $\lambda = 5.$
Based on a million samples of size ten, results should
be reliable to 2 or 3 significant digits.

```
 m = 10^6;  lam = 5;  n = 10
 x = rexp(m*n, lam)
 DTA = matrix(x, nrow=m)      # m x n matrix, each row a sample
 a = rowMeans(DTA)            # vector of m sample means
 lam.hat = 1/a                # vector of m estimates
 mean(lam.hat);  sd(lam.hat)
 ## 5.556989                  # aprx E(est)
 ## 1.966194                  # aprx SD(est)
 sqrt(mean((lam.hat - lam)^2))
 ## 2.043564                  # aprx root mean sq error of est
 lam.unb = ((n-1)/n)*lam.hat  # unbiased est
 mean(lam.unb);  sd(lam.unb)
 ## 5.00129
 ## 1.769575
 sqrt(mean((lam.unb - lam)^2))
 ## 1.769574
```

I seem to recall that the usual method of finding moments of $1/\bar X$ is to
recognize that $\bar X$ has a gamma distribution, and then
to recognize that the integrand of a power of $1/\bar X$ times
the PDF of $\bar X$ is similar to the PDF of a related distribution.

---

**Addendum** (prompted by Comment): If $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n$
are a random sample from $Exp(rate = \lambda),$ then one
can use moment generating functions to show that 
$T = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i \sim Gamma(n, \lambda),$ which
has density function 
$f_T(t) = \frac{\lambda^n}{(n-1)!} t^{n-1} e^{-\lambda t},$ for
$t > 0.$

Then $$E(1/T) = \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{t} f_T(t)\,dt
= \int_0^\infty \frac{\lambda^n}{(n-1)!} t^{n-2} e^{-\lambda t}\,dt
= \frac{\lambda}{n-1} \int_0^\infty g(t)\,dt,$$
where $g(t)$ is the density of $Gamma(n-1, \lambda)$, so that
the last integral is unity and $E(1/T) = \lambda/(n-1).$
Hence $E\left(\frac{n-1}{T}\right) = \lambda$ and $\hat \lambda = 1/\bar X$ is biased. This is the method
to which I referred in the last paragraph of my original Answer.
Something similar works for evaluating $E(1/T^2).$

The simulation below illustrates that $T \sim Gamma(n, \lambda),$
again with $n = 10$ and $\lambda = 5.$

```
 m = 10^6;  lam = 5;  n = 10
 x = rexp(m*n, lam)
 DTA = matrix(x, nrow=m)      # m x n matrix, each row a sample
 t = rowSums(DTA)
 hist(t, prob=T,  col="wheat")
 curve(dgamma(x,n,lam), lwd=2, col="blue", add=T)
```

[image]

Comment: I can't seem to prove that using $\hat{\lambda}=n/\sum X_i$ is biased. And what would the variance be?

Comment: OK, see Addendum for a start.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I'll try to calculate the variance using moments.